# LikeDislike modx evo

Tags: cms, modx

делаю вывод LikeDislike

пытаюсь записать в тв лайки и дизлайки вот так

```
 [[!LikeDislike? 
                &likeId='[[*id]]' 
                &name=`[[*pagetitle]]` 
                &rating=`type=1,tv=LikeDislike,output=votes_up`
                &rating=`type=1,tv=Dislike,output=votes_down`
                &tpl=`likedislik_up_down` 
                &name=`Demo likedislik_up_down`
              ]]
```

но он как-то то записывает по отдельности, то одинаковые значения в тв LikeDilike и Dislike

Comment: Причем тут js и php??

Comment: @DimenSi - не надо спрашивать, надо редактировать тэги и отправлять правку на проверку.

Comment: Правку отправил, ком потереть забыл.